# Select field serialize not working via ajax

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, select, serialization

I have 3 select menus. I need to send the values over ajax as an array which I'm attempting to do using `serialize()`. The problem is that it's only sending 1 value instead of all 3. Any ideas what's going on?

```js
var menu = $('select[name^="menu"]').serialize();
console.log(menu);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="menu[]">
  <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
<select name="menu[]">
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
</select>
<select name="menu[]">
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
```

```
var menu = $('select[name^="menu"]').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"www.example.com/submit.php",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: 'menudata='+menu+'&name=bob',
    success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
    },error: function() {
       alert('error occurred')
    }
})
```

Comment: I've placed your code in to an executable snippet where you can see it works correctly. Are you sure the issue is with the user of `serialize()` and not that the value being sent incorrectly in your AJAX logic, or even an issue with how the request is handled on the server side?

Comment: i've updated my answer to include my ajax request

Comment: Thanks - that's the issue. You're appending a querystring to the value of a property, which, unless you handle this specific case on your server side (which is a *very* odd thing to be doing) it will not work. Change the `data` property to just this: `data: menu,`. Then in your server code, receive the array of `menu` values and work with them as required.

Comment: i'ved updated the ajax again. I have added another querystring in there with standard single inputs. Serverside i'm converting the array string into another array to do some magic (odd I know) but i just need to get the all values of the menu array and link to a querystring

Comment: In that case use `data: menu + '&name=bob'`

Comment: you beauty!!! it works! (i've never thought to do it like that) big big thank you! :) :)

Comment: Glad to help :) I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with how you are sending the querystring to the server in your AJAX request, not with how `serialize()` is formatting the output.

To fix the issue remove the `menudata=` property name from the querystring you manually create:

```js
data: menu + '&name=bob',
```